# ActiveRecordで複数の関連を持つcollectionに対する追加の方法

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

ActiveRecordで複数の関連を持つcollectionに、新たなレコードを追加させたい場合の実装について悩んでいます。

まず、テーブル構成を示します。

---

### テーブル

- users … ユーザの情報を保持するテーブル
- entries … 記事の情報を保持するテーブル
- laters … "あとで読む"に設定した記事とユーザを紐付ける中間テーブル
- checks … "既読"に設定した記事とユーザを紐付ける中間テーブル

### アソシエーション

- user → laters → entrys
  ※ userはlatersを中間テーブルとして`has_many: entries`な関連を持つ
- user → checks → entrys
  ※ userはchecksを中間テーブルとして`has_many: entries`な関連を持つ

---

### 質問

下記のように既読記事の追加（user-check-entryの紐付けの追加）の実装を行ったのですが意図どおりに動きません。

```
entry = Entry.new
  ：
entry.save
User.find(1).entries<<entry
```

意図するところは、checksテーブルに紐付けのレコードがinsertされることですが、実際にはlatersテーブルにinsertされてしまいます。

複数の関連を持つcollectionに、明示的に「こっちの紐付けを追加」というような操作はできますでしょうか。

---

### ソースコード

Github
https://github.com/hogesuke/tech-book/tree/master/model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問のアソシエーションの記述から、User モデルは以下の様な記述を試されたと仮定して話を進めます。
（前提が違っていたら申し訳ありません。）

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, :through => :laters
  has_many :entries, :through => :checks
end
```

上記のような場合、entries に、（違うテーブルを介して）2つのリレーションを貼ろうとしていますが、名前が同じになるため、衝突しているのだと思います。（なので、質問のようにlatersしか更新されないし、どちらかを選んで更新をかけることが出来ません）

このような場合、アクセスするための名前を分けることで、問題が解決するかと思います。
具体的には以下の様な感じです。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :later_entries, :through => :laters, :source => 'entry'
  has_many :check_entries, :through => :checks, :source => 'entry'
end
```

その後、

```
entry = Entry.new
  # ：
entry.save
User.find(1).check_entries << entry
```

などとする事で、checksテーブルに紐付けのレコードがinsertされるかと思います。

### 参考URL

- [Rails マニュアル: has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)
- [Coma's Tech Blog: has_many :through の関連に同一モデルを含む場合](http://www.coma-tech.com/archives/223/)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

github上のソースコードが古い状態のもので混乱させてしまっていますね…すみません。

前提については、書いて頂いてる内容で正しいです。
おそらく、提示いただいた名前を分けるというやり方で解決できそうに思います。
作業できる環境に戻りましたら試してみたいと思います。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: 提示の方法で解決しました！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`laters` に入ってしまうのは https://github.com/hogesuke/tech-book/blob/master/model/user.rb#L4 で

```
has_many :entries, :through => :laters
```

しているからでしょう。

対応方法は少なくとも以下の2つが考えられそうです。

1. `User` に `Checks` 用 の `has_many' を追加定義する
2. 直接 `Checks` に追加する

前者のモデルへの追加はこんな感じです。

```
has_many :checked_entries, :through => :later
```

で実際に追加するコードは以下のとおりです。

```
entry = Entry.new
：
entry.save
User.find(1).checked_entries << entry
```

それに対して後者のコードはこんな感じになるでしょうか。

```
entry = Entry.new
：
entry.save
check = Check.new({user: User.find(1), entry: entry})
check.save
```

例示したコードはざっくり書いただけで、細かいチェックはしてないので適宜修正していただければ。

---

#### 追記

上記は、いまのDBスキーマを変えずにやるなら、という前提です。

> 複数の関連を持つcollectionに、明示的に「こっちの紐付けを追加」というような操作はできますでしょうか。

これにこたえるにはDBスキーマを変える必要があります。`Checks` と `Laters` に代えて、`ChecksOrLaters` みたいな中間テーブルを追加し、どちらの関連性であるかを `relationType` といったフィールドで記録するという方法は考えられます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。 github上のソースコードが古い状態のもので混乱させてしまっていますね…すみません。

アソシエーションについては、もうひとつの回答で示していただいたように実装しています。
アソシエーション上で名前を変えることができるようなので、それを試してみたいと思います。